# Can't prevent Solr spellcheck component delimiting on characters

Tags: search, solr, spell-checking

I can't seem to prevent the Solr spellcheck component from delimiting words by characters. This is the field which is the basis of my spelling suggestions:

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

And this is my main general use field type:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

When I run the query:

`skiny jen\"as`

I am returned the collated spelling suggestion of:

`"skinny jeans\\\"wash"`

This seems odd because the query has been broken into `skiny`, `jen` and `as` but collated together in this format. When I use the Solr analyzer to see what's being done to my query, these are the end  results I get for the two field types (which give me what I would expect):

text_en: `skini` |  `jen\"a`

textSpell: `skiny` | `jen\"as`

So with this in mind, why are `jen` and `as` being processed seperately in the token `jen\"as`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to specify `spellcheck.q` and `q` together. That way the main query results are based on `q` but the spelling suggestion on `spellcheck.q`. It looks like Solr was tokenizing and applying some filters to `q`.